# 104: Connection reset by peer while reading response header from upstream (Nginx)

Tags: nginx, php, http

I have a server which was working ok until 3rd Oct 2013 at 10:50am when it began to intermittently return "502 Bad Gateway" errors to the client.

Approximately 4 out of 5 browser requests succeed but about 1 in 5 fail with a 502.

The nginx error log contains many hundreds of these errors;

```
2013/10/05 06:28:17 [error] 3111#0: *54528 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 66.249.66.75, server: www.bec-components.co.uk  request: ""GET /?_n=Fridgefreezer/Hotpoint/8591P;_i=x8078 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "www.bec-components.co.uk"
```

However the PHP error log does not contain any matching errors.

**Is there a way to get PHP to give me more info about why it is resetting the connection?**

This is `nginx.conf`;

```
user              www-data;
worker_processes  4;
error_log         /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid               /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
   worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
  include          /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  access_log       /var/log/nginx/access.log;

  sendfile               on;
  keepalive_timeout      30;
  tcp_nodelay            on;
  client_max_body_size   100m;

  gzip         on;
  gzip_types   text/plain application/xml text/javascript application/x-javascript text/css;
  gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";

  include /gvol/sites/*/nginx.conf;

}
```

And this is the `.conf` for this site;

```
server {

  server_name   www.bec-components.co.uk bec3.uk.to bec4.uk.to bec.home;
  root          /gvol/sites/bec/www/;
  index         index.php index.html;

  location ~ \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
    expires        2592000;   # 30 days
    log_not_found  off;
  }

  ## Trigger client to download instead of display '.xml' files.
  location ~ \.xml$ {
    add_header Content-disposition "attachment; filename=$1";
  }

   location ~ \.php$ {
      fastcgi_read_timeout  3600;
      include               /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
      keepalive_timeout     0;
      fastcgi_param         SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      fastcgi_pass          127.0.0.1:9000;
      fastcgi_index         index.php;
   }
}

## bec-components.co.uk ##
server {
   server_name   bec-components.co.uk;
   rewrite       ^/(.*) http://www.bec-components.co.uk$1 permanent;
}
```

Comment: What was changed on that day? Updated your application or PHP? What's your application? Did you enable debugging in php-fpm?

Comment: Nothing was changed on that day. Server config was not changed, nor were any PHP scripts. It's not out of disk space. My application is just a set of `PHP` scripts. I'm not using `php-fpm`, I'm just running `php-fastcgi` by doing `php-cgi -b 127.0.0.1:9000`. It's been working without fault for 3 years. I can't work out why it has developed this issue.

Comment: I had similar issue recently where nginx was complaining about Connection reset by peer while reading response header from upstream, in my case it was uWSGI which was the real problem, restarting uWSGI fixed the issue for me, as to why it was happening is a separate issue.

Comment: Your upstream service ( `php-cgi -b 127.0.0.1:9000` ) is failing intermittently, perhaps due to increased traffic and lack of resources.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I'd always trust if my web servers are telling me `502 Bad Gateway`.

- What is the uptime of your FastCGI/NGINX process?
- Do you monitor network connections?
- Can you confirm/deny a change of visitors count around that day?

### What the error means

Your FastCGI process is not accessible by NGINX; either to slow or not corresponding at all. Bad gateway means that NGINX cannot complete the `fastcgi_pass` step to that defined resources listening on `127.0.0.1:9000` and **at that very specific moment**.

Your inital error logs tells it all:

```bash
recv() failed 
    -> nginx failed

(104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, 
    -> no complete answer, or no answer at all
upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", 
    -> who is he, who failed???
```

From my limited point of view, I'd suggest:

- To restart your FastCGI process or server
- To check your `access.log`
- To enable enable `debug.log`

Comment: Ok. What are my webservers telling me?

Comment: see my edit (what does it mean)

Comment: I see, so the `Gateway` in this case is the PHP server. Thank you.

Comment: `restart your fastcgi_process / server` is what helped me, thans

Answer (score 20):

I know this topic is old, but it still continues to pop up occasionally, so, looking for answers on the web, I came up with the following three possibilities:

1. A programming error is sometimes segfaulting php-fpm, which in turn means that the connection with nginx will be severed. This will usually leave at least some logs around and/or core dumps, which can be analysed further.
2. For some reason, PHP is not being able to write a session file (usually: `session.save_path = "/var/lib/php/sessions"`). This can be bad permissions, bad ownership, bad user/group, or more esoteric/obscure issues like running out of inodes on that directory (or even a full disk!). This will usually *not* leave many core dumps around and possibly not even anything on the PHP error logs.
3. Even more tricky to debug: an extension is misbehaving (occasionally hitting some kind of inner limit, or a bug which is not triggered all the time), segfaulting, and bringing the php-fpm process down with it — thus closing the connection with nginx. The usual culprits are APC, memcache/d, etc. (in my case it was the New Relic extension), so the idea here is to turn each extension off until the error disappears.

Comment: +1 In my case it was #1 - programming error.

Comment: We ran into this error and disabling the New Relic APM PHP extension revealed a more specific error that allowed us to track down the problem:
[29-Jan-2018 16:47:48 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 805306368 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Pricing/Price/ConfigurableRegularPrice.php on line 142
[29-Jan-2018 16:47:48 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 805306368 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 323584 bytes) in Unknown on line 0
My guess is that New Relic choked on the "Unknown" path.

Comment: ty in my case the code was segfaulting somehow, removing line by line gave me this confirmation.

Answer (score 11):

Kept getting this as well. Solved it by increasing the `opcache` memory limit, if you use it (replacement for APC). Seems PHP-FPM dropped connections whenever the cache got too full. This is also the reason why shgnInc's answer fixes it for a short time.

So find the file `/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini` (or equivalent in your distribution) and increase `memory_consumption` to whatever level your site needs. Disabling `opcache` may also work.

```
[opcache]
opcache.memory_consumption = 196
```

Comment: how does one disable `opcache` ?

Comment: @JoãoPimentelFerreira `opcache.enable = 0` in php.ini would do it

Answer (score 6):

In my case of same problem, I just restart the `php-fpm` service so it solved.

```
sudo service php5-fpm restart
```

Or some times this problem happen because of huge of requests. By default the `pm.max_requests` in php5-fpm maybe is 100 or below.

To solve it increase its value depend on the your site's requests, For example 500.

And after the you have to restart the  service

Answer (score 2):

You may want to consider this git on github:
https://gist.github.com/amichaelgrant/90d99d7d5d48bf8fd209

I encountered a similar situation, when I checked error logs for my upstream servers they were reporting some ulimit error so I increased that to 1000000(on both the upstream and nginx boxes) and everything worked fine

Answer (score 2):

In my case, disabling *xdebug* extension did help.

Comment: ditto, in my case i set a condition for a breakpoint and at that moment i disabled the breackpoint the error was gone.

Answer (score 2):

This issue may also arise if a PHP-FPM process exceeds its allocated memory limit. When this happens, the connection between NGINX and PHP-FPM is severed and NGINX returns a `502 Bad Gateway`. The PHP-FPM process memory limit is controlled by the `memory_limit` variable. This can be set with `php_admin_value[memory_limit]` in the PHP-FPM configuration file.

It is important to note that the memory limit applies on a **per-script** basis. With `n` PHP-FPM processes, the total memory usage can be up to `memory_limit * n`.  Be sure to check that your machine has sufficient memory headroom!

Answer (score 1):

I just had a similar problem:

You connect to `php-fpm` on Port `9000`.  (`fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000`)

Standard configuration on Ubuntu on my server is:

`/etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`:

`listen = /run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock`

you have to change this to:

`listen = 0.0.0.0:9000`

In my case, I did update my server 1 1/2 Months ago, overwriting my custom configuration with the default. Now having restarted `php-fpm` this error came to effect with delay.

Answer (score 1):

For me it was the server running out of memory and php-fpm getting killed by OOM killer. The solution was to increase amount of server memory.

Answer (score 1):

For me it was because php-fpm was hitting the `max_children` limit. The php-fpm log for the pool in question pointed me in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar issue: random `Connection reset by peer` when server was under load. Eventually found it was due to a difference in `keepalive_timeout` values between nginx and upstream (gunicorn in my case). Nginx was at 75s and upstream was just a few seconds. Thus sometimes upstream dropped the connection and nginx didn't understand why.

Increasing upstream value to be identical to nginx' solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using multiple reverse proxies, you should be aware that nginx will send a connection reset in some situations. If for instance you are getting "n worker_connections are not enough" in your logs, that's the source of the connection reset. Each request on a reverse proxy requires 2 `worker_connections`. If you don't know that then your margin of safety may not be a margin at all.

Answer (score 0):

Culprit for me in 2023 was Tideways on PHP 8.2. Removing it removes the PHP crash.

Looking for an alternative... Back to xhprof certainly (via PECL: https://pecl.php.net/package/xhprof)