# Mysterious Upstream Client ::ffff:81.70.140.65...changes on each error

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, connection, 500-error, reset

I read the following post:

[nginx errors recv failed 104](https://serverfault.com/questions/543999/nginx-errors-recv-failed-104-connection-reset-by-peer-while-reading-respon)

...but have a different question...

I'm curious to know why there is ANY reference to this mysterious upstream source:

```
::ffff:81.70.140.65
```

...which point to   s51468c41.adsl.online.nl

Please note: the reason i got the error is because i was testing my own site books.clmitchell.net from my home in North Carolina.

And, of course, I'm trying to understand why i'm getting a 500 internal server error from this subdomain (joomla 2.5) when my other subdomain (main.clmitchell.net, joomla 1.5) is working fine.

The other thing i noticed is that the upstream source is a different IP address every time:

81.70.140.65 s51468c41.adsl.online.nl

66.192.73.6 Milwaukee

66.249.67.143   crawl-66-249-67-143.googlebot.com

66.249.67.43 another googlebot

Here is the entire error:

```
2014/09/21 08:07:55 [error] 1651#0: *5431 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: ::ffff:81.70.140.65, server clmitchell.net, request: "GET /mnub3/132-artb3c22.html HTTP/1.0", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "books.clmitchell.net"
```

Thank you!

default site:

```
server {
# Replace this port with the right one for your requirements
listen [::]:80 ipv6only=off;

\# Multiple hostnames separated by spaces. Replace these as well.
server_name clmitchell.net www.clmitchell.net main.clmitchell.net books.clmitchell.net         dna.clmitchell.net help.clmitchell.net history.clmitchell.net svcs.clmitchell.net;
server_name_in_redirect off;

root /var/www/$host;

error_page 401 /error/401.shtml;
error_page 402 /error/402.shtml;
error_page 403 /error/403.shtml;
error_page 404 /error/404.shtml;
error_page 500 501 502 503 504 /error/500.shtml;

location ^~ /error/ {
internal;
root /var/www/www.clmitchell.net;
}


access_log /var/log/nginx/$host-access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

index index.php index.html index.htm default.html default.htm;
\# Support Clean (aka Search Engine Friendly) URLs
location / {
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}

\# serve static files directly
location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico)$ {
access_log off;
expires max;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
try_files $uri =404;
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
fastcgi_index index.php;
include fastcgi_params;
}

location ~ \.scm$ {
include fastcgi_params;
fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
\# By all means use a different server for the fcgi processes if you need to
fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9981;
}

location ~ /\.ht {
deny all;
}
}
```

Comment: Those are not your upstream, they are the IP addresses of the user who was visiting your site!

Comment: Thank you for clarifying...why would one of my sites work and the other not work? Following is my default site:

Comment: Because your application crashed.

Comment: The only thing i changed recently was

short_open_tag=On

...in php.ini

Comment: the other interesting fact is that i can load the admin pages, no prob: books.clmitchell.net/administrator

Comment: SOLVED: site was just moved from BlueHost to Digital Ocean; log and temp directories were pointing to wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: site was just moved from BlueHost to Digital Ocean; log and temp directories were pointing to wrong place (thought i had already corrected that).